# Rsync folder with a million files, but very small incremental daily updates

Tags: grep, find, rsync

we run an `rsync` on a large folder. This has close to a million files inside it including html, jsp, gif/jpg, etc. We only need to of course incrementally update files. Just a few JSP and HTML files are updated in this folder, and we need this server to `rsync` to a different server, same folder.

Sometimes rsync is running quite slow these days, so one of our IT team members created this command:

```
find /usr/home/foldername \
-type f -name *.jsp -exec \
grep -l <ssi:include src=[^$]*${ {} ;`
```

This looks for only specific files which have `JSP` extension and which contain certain kinds of text, because these are the files which we need to `rsync`. But this command is consuming a lot of memory. I think it's a stupid way to rsync, but I'm being told this is how things will work.

Some googling suggests that this should work on this folder too:

```
rsync -a --update --progress --rsh --partial /usr/home/foldername /destination/server
```

I'm worried that this will be too slow on a daily basis, but I can't imagine why this will be slower than that silly find option that our IT folks are recommending. Any ideas about large directory rsyncs in the real world?

Comment: How many files on average are updated daily? rsync should usually only be copying files that are not present or different than the target. Also rsync should be fast, even for large files.

Comment: Thank you. About 100 files are updated daily. Not a huge number. So one of our ideas has been -- can we leave a shell of folders on this server and do something like "one way sync", so that any file not in the destination server will be uploaded, but leave stuff alone that's not on this server yet exists on the destination server. This way we keep this server small, and rsync's work is minimal to check timestamps etc. Would this work? After rsync, we can delete the files from this local server.

Comment: Yes, that is how rsync is usually implemented; I'm not sure what you mean though by deleting the files from the local server. If it's a daily job of syncing the files from server1 to server2 why would you delete the files? generally rsync would be used to match exactly what was on server1 (in specific directory or otherwise), so if files are deleted on server1 for example they wouldn't exist on server2 either after rsyncing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `find` command will *not* be faster than the `rsync` scan, and the `grep` command must be slower than `rsync` because it requires reading *all* the text from all the `.jsp` files.

The only way a find-and-grep could be faster is if

1. The timestamps on your files do not match, so `rsync` has to checksum the contents (on both sides!)

   This seems unlikely, since you're using `-a` that will sync the timestamps properly (because `-a` implies `-t`). However, it can happen if the file-systems on the different machines allow different timestamp precision (e.g. Linux vs. Windows), in which case the `--modify-window` option is what you need.
2. There are many more files changed than the ones you care about, and `rsync` is transferring those also.

   If this is the case then you can limit the transfer to `.jsp` files like this:

   ```
   --include '*.jsp' --include '*/' --exclude '*'
   ```

   (Include all `.jsp` files and all directories, but exclude everything else.)
3. `rsync` does the scan up front, then does the compare (possibly using lots of RAM), then does the transfer, where as find/grep/copy does it *now*.

   This used to be a problem, but `rsync` ought to do an incremental recursive scan as long as both local and remote versions are 3.0.0 or greater, and you don't use any of the fancy delete or delay options that force an up-front scan (see `--recursive` in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.